# Enemy nodes occasionally gets stuck on a wall

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have enemy nodes spawning on platforms that have edges, I don't want my enemies to be lemmings and fall off, so I created two separate sprite nodes that act as invisible walls and had the walls set as a **connected joint on to the platform** so that when the enemy contacts either wall, they turn back.

Problem is that sometimes the enemy node ignores the contact entirely and just run in place exactly where the contact should've worked.

I use NSLogs to track if the enemy nodes contacting the walls, but like I said, the enemy flat-out **ignores** that and I don't receive a log saying the enemy has contacted the wall and so the contact method doesn't occur.

I wanted to rectify that by making the walls repeat an action forever that moves them back one pixel and then forward one pixel, however the actions don't seem to be working properly, and so Im at a loss onto how to fix it. Any info would be gladly appreciated.

**The Platform Generator Method**

```
-(void)createPlatform {

    SKAction *shake1 = [SKAction moveByX:1 y:0 duration:.1];
    SKAction *shake2 = [SKAction moveByX:-1 y:0 duration:.1];
    SKAction *shake3 = [SKAction sequence:@[shake1, shake2]];
    contactLineShake = [SKAction repeatActionForever:shake3];

    variaPlatform = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"shortPlatform3-Checkered"];
    variaPlatform.name = @"variaPlatform";
    variaPlatform.zPosition = 2;
    variaPlatform.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:variaPlatform.size];
    variaPlatform.physicsBody.friction = 1;
    variaPlatform.physicsBody.linearDamping = 1;
    variaPlatform.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = fPlatformCategory;
    variaPlatform.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = fPlayerCategory | fEnemyCategory;
    variaPlatform.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = fPlayerCategory | fEnemyCategory;
    variaPlatform.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
    variaPlatform.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
    variaPlatform.position = CGPointMake(700, variaPlatform.position.y - 129);

    contactLine1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor blueColor] size:CGSizeMake(5, 21)];
    contactLine1.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:contactLine1.size];
    contactLine1.hidden = NO;
    contactLine1.position = CGPointMake(variaPlatform.position.x - 107, variaPlatform.position.y + 36);
    contactLine1.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = fContactEnemyCategory1;
    contactLine1.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = fEnemyCategory | fMainPlatformCategory;
    contactLine1.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;

    contactLine2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor blueColor] size:CGSizeMake(5, 21)];
    contactLine2.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:contactLine2.size];
    contactLine2.hidden = NO;
    contactLine2.position = CGPointMake(variaPlatform.position.x + 107, variaPlatform.position.y + 36);
    contactLine2.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = fContactEnemyCategory2;
    contactLine2.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = fEnemyCategory | fMainPlatformCategory;
    contactLine2.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;

    [self addChild:contactLine1];
    [self addChild:contactLine2];
    [self addChild:variaPlatform];
    [self connectNode1:variaPlatform toNode2:contactLine1];
    [self connectNode1:variaPlatform toNode2:contactLine2];

    [variaPlatform runAction:variaActions];
    [contactLine1 runAction:contactLineShake];
    [contactLine2 runAction:contactLineShake];

}
```

**The Contact Method**

```
// Returns a node that matches the specified category.
static inline SKSpriteNode *nodeFromBody(SKPhysicsBody *body1, SKPhysicsBody *body2, uint32_t category) {
    SKSpriteNode *node = nil;
    if (body1.categoryBitMask & category) {
        node = (SKSpriteNode *)body1.node;
    }
    else if (body2.categoryBitMask & category) {
        node = (SKSpriteNode *)body2.node;
    }
    return node;
}

-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {
    SKPhysicsBody *firstBody, *secondBody;
    SKSpriteNode *player = nil;
    SKSpriteNode *enemy = nil;
    SKSpriteNode *contactLineBody1 = nil;
    SKSpriteNode *contactLineBody2 = nil;

    firstBody = contact.bodyA;
    secondBody = contact.bodyB;

    player = nodeFromBody(firstBody, secondBody, fPlayerCategory);
    enemy = nodeFromBody(firstBody, secondBody, fEnemyCategory);
    contactLineBody1 = nodeFromBody(firstBody, secondBody, fContactEnemyCategory1);
    contactLineBody2 = nodeFromBody(firstBody, secondBody, fContactEnemyCategory2);

    if (((firstBody.categoryBitMask & fEnemyCategory) != 0) && ((secondBody.categoryBitMask & fContactEnemyCategory1) != 0)) {
        [enemy removeAllActions];
        [enemy runAction:runReverseForeverAnimation];
        [enemy runAction:enemyMoveRight1];

        contactLeft++;
        if (contactLeft >= 1) {
            [enemy removeAllActions];
            [enemy runAction:runReverseForeverAnimation];
            [enemy runAction:enemyMoveRight1];
            [enemy.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(1, 0)];
        }
        NSLog(@"contact Left %i", contactLeft);
        contactRight = 0;
    }

    if (((firstBody.categoryBitMask & fEnemyCategory) != 0) && ((secondBody.categoryBitMask & fContactEnemyCategory2) != 0)) {
        [enemy removeAllActions];
        [enemy runAction:runForeverAnimation];
        [enemy runAction:enemyMoveLeft1];

        contactRight++;
        if (contactRight >= 1) {
            [enemy removeAllActions];
            [enemy runAction:runForeverAnimation];
            [enemy runAction:enemyMoveLeft1];
            [enemy.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(-1, 0)];
        }
        NSLog(@"contact Right %i", contactRight);
        contactLeft = 0;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your checks in `didBeginContact:` don't take in to account that there's no guarantee regarding which body is which in `SKPhysicsContact`.  It looks like you already took that in to account when getting the nodes for `player`, `enemy`, `contactLineBody1`, and `contactLineBody2` though, so we can just use those in your `if` statements:

Instead of:

```
if (((firstBody.categoryBitMask & fEnemyCategory) != 0) && ((secondBody.categoryBitMask & fContactEnemyCategory1) != 0))

// ...

if (((firstBody.categoryBitMask & fEnemyCategory) != 0) && ((secondBody.categoryBitMask & fContactEnemyCategory2) != 0))
```

Just do:

```
if (enemy && contactLineBody1)

// ...

if (enemy && contactLineBody2)
```